# Counting number of times value appears in column across all rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand how to count the number of times a value occurs in a column and output it in such a way that I can easily create graphs with it.

I have a form which stores the questions in one table and the answers in another.

Fields Table

| id | key | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email | Email |
| 2 | department | Department |
| 3 | activities_interest | What activities are you interested in? |

Meta Table

| id | field_id | value | form_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo@bar.com | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Sales | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | Sport | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | bar@foo.com | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | Sales | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | Cars | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | new@bar.com | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | Marketing | 3 |
| 9 | 3 | Cars | 3 |
| 10 | 1 | fooboo@bar.com | 4 |
| 11 | 2 | IT | 4 |
| 12 | 3 | Food | 4 |

The input of the form will be done via drop down so the responses will be limited to a certain number.

I am trying to write a script that outputs the data as follows

| field_id | value | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Sales | 2 |
| 2 | Marketing | 1 |
| 2 | IT | 1 |
| 3 | Cars | 2 |
| 3 | Sport | 1 |
| 3 | Food | 1 |

I apologise for the query below, but its where I'm currently at..

```
SELECT metas.`id`,
       metas.`field_id`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fields.`field_key` = 'department' THEN metas.`meta_value` ELSE NULL END) Department,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fields.`field_key` = 'email' THEN metas.`meta_value` ELSE NULL END) Email,
       COUNT(fields.`id`) Total
FROM fields
  INNER JOIN metas
     ON fields.`id` = metas.`field_id`
GROUP   BY metas.`item_id`
ORDER BY metas.`item_id`
```

Comment: What is it currently giving you in the output?

Comment: The total comes through as either 15, 16 or 17 each time and the results of course aren't yet grouped

Comment: Why do you require join in this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field_id, value, count(*) FROM metas group by value;
```

I don't think you require join in this as the fields you want in output can be derived from metas only.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are other columns which I'd need to display which I removed as an attempt to make things simpler.

Comment: Did this help, or should I update the answer with join?

Comment: I'm definitely closer than I was! The numbers being returned by the count aren't quite right but it is definitely starting to shape up how I expected it to. If you could that would be fantastic, thank you

Comment: Can you update what you exactly require and how the number returned by count isn't right?